# how to refactor these methods?

Tags: java

I have 4 methods mostly similar but I can't figure out how to refactor them

```
public String listWeatherConditions()
{
    String retVal = "";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    for(Map.Entry<String , ArrayList<Weather>> entry : this.weathers.entrySet())
    {
        retVal = String.format("\n Data From %s \n", entry.getKey());
        retVal += String.format("displaying \tWeather Conditions hPa\n","");
        for (Weather element : this.weathers.get(entry.getKey()))
                {

                    retVal += String.format("%s\t\t%s\n",formatter.format(element.getCalculatedDate()) , element.getConditions() );
                }
    }

    retVal += "--------------------";
    return retVal;
}

public String listWind()
{
    String retVal = "";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    for(Map.Entry<String , ArrayList<Weather>> entry : this.weathers.entrySet())
    {
        retVal = String.format("\n Data From %s \n", entry.getKey());
        retVal += String.format("displaying \tWind Direction\tWind SpeedKm/h\tWindDirDegrees\n","");
        for (Weather element : this.weathers.get(entry.getKey()))
                {

                    retVal += String.format("%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", formatter.format(element.getCalculatedDate()), element.getWindDirection() , element.getWindSpeedKmh() , element.getWindDirDegrees() );
                }
    }

    retVal += "--------------------";
    return retVal;

}
```

how can I refactor them?

Comment: I copied only two of them here just for convenience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see difference between the two methods in at least two points: you have different headers and you have different formatting. In the generic method different headers could be handled simply by passing a String parameter. The second problem could be addressed by including a parameter which indicates how to format a string and you handle this in your method correspondingly.

If you want a really universal method, you can do it through an interface. Something like this:

```
interface WeatherFormatter {
    String formatWeather(Weather weather);
}
```

Your generic method:

```
public String listConditions(String header, WeatherFormatter weatherFormatter) {
    String retVal = "";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    for(Map.Entry<String , ArrayList<Weather>> entry : this.weathers.entrySet()) {
        retVal = String.format("\n Data From %s \n", entry.getKey());
        retVal += header;
        for (Weather element : this.weathers.get(entry.getKey())) {
            retVal += weatherFormatter.formatWeather(weather);
        }
    }
    retVal += "--------------------";
    return retVal;
}
```

And you call your generic method like this:

```
listConditions("displaying \tWeather Conditions hPa\n", new WeatherFormatter() {
    String formatWeather(Weather weather) {
        return String.format("%s\t\t%s\n", formatter.format(weather.getCalculatedDate()), weather.getConditions());
    }
});
```

One more idea: you can combine both of my suggestions. You create a parameter for the method which is not just an interface, but an enum implementing this interface instead. In your enum declaration you implement your `formatWeather()` method for each constant. That would be a very object-oriented design.

Comment: +1. Exactly the same idea as mine, but with a better and sooner explanation.

Comment: +1 Just posted the same idea :D

Comment: I need some help about how to implement the things that you say here, this is my first time of refactoring such this thing and I really don't get it how to implement a generic loop and then get dynamic value out of it , I have invited u to gtalk hope u answer to it.

Comment: @austinpowers I don't actually understand what you need. You have code snippets, all you have to do is to copy them to your code. I've edited the answer and included the entire generic method. Beyond this I don't think there's anything to be said in regard to your question. If you have more questions, specific ones, then you're welcome to ask them separately.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your code correctly, it seems that the only difference between the methods is how you treat the Weather objects in the loop.  In this case, you are just appending Strings.  It might be worth considering one method to do the looping, and have it delegate the actual "what do I do with this" to an object you pass in.

For example, you could create an interface to represent the "do something" parts...

```
public Interface WeatherWork {
    public String formatWeatherString(Weather weather);
}
```

And implement it once for each type of output you desire...

```
public class WindWorker implements WeatherWork {
   public String formatWeatherString(Weather weather) {
      return String.format("%s\t\t%s\n",formatter.format(weather.getCalculatedDate()) , weather.getConditions());
   }
}
```

And then, reimplement your weather looping code to take one of these new objects...

```
public String listWind() {
   return formatWeather(new WindWorker());
}
```

And formatWeather() would do the looping...

```
public String formatWeather(WeatherWork worker) {
   String retVal = "";
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
   for(Map.Entry<String , ArrayList<Weather>> entry : this.weathers.entrySet()) {
    retVal = String.format("\n Data From %s \n", entry.getKey());
    for (Weather element : this.weathers.get(entry.getKey())) {
         retVal += worker.formatWeatherString(element);
    }

   retVal += "--------------------";
   return retVal;
}
```

EDIT: Oops, I missed the headers.  You get the idea, you can put them in WeatherWorker.  Just add a method to the interface to return the header and implement it in the implementation classes.

Comment: +1 Exatly the same idea as mine :) This would have been a lot easier with Lambda predicates

Comment: @GETah As soon as I saw this question I thought the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Using the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern to define a formatting strategy on the fly

```
public String listWeatherFeature(IFormatterStrategy formatStrategy){
    String retVal = "";
    for(Map.Entry<String , ArrayList<Weather>> entry : this.weathers.entrySet()){
        retVal = String.format("\n Data From %s \n", entry.getKey());
         for (Weather element : this.weathers.get(entry.getKey())){
           retVal += formatStrategy.formatElement(element);
        }
    }
    retVal += "--------------------";
    return retVal;
}

public interface IFormatterStrategy{
   String formatElement(Weather element);
}

public class WindFormatterStrategy implements IFormatter{
   String formatElement(Weather element){
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
      return String.format("%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", formatter.format(element.getCalculatedDate()), element.getWindDirection() , element.getWindSpeedKmh() , element.getWindDirDegrees() );
   }
} 

public class WeatherFormatterStrategy implements IFormatter{
   String formatElement(Weather element){
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
      return String.format("%s\t\t%s\n",formatter.format(element.getCalculatedDate()) , element.getConditions() );
   }
}

// Usage
// Wind:  
String result = String.format("displaying \tWeather Conditions hPa\n","");
result  += listWeatherFeature(new WeatherFormatterStrategy());
// Weather
String result = String.format("displaying \tWeather Conditions hPa\n","");
result += listWeatherFeature(new WindFormatterStrategy());
```